# ActiveMq - Durable Topic - Concurrency

Tags: activemq-classic

I have multiple durable subscribers listening to a Durable-Topic. Say, all the subscribers are configured to concurrently handle messages to '2-8'.

Among these subscribers, one is not able to process the messages due to some runtime dependencies (say, an external service is unavailable), so this subscriber throws custom `RuntimeException` to allow ActiveMq to redeliver the message 7 times (default). What I see in the Activemq administrative console is, there are too many redelivery attempts for this particular subscriber - also, I see there dequeue count increases drastically, for one message, it increases more 36 and not consistent. Why is it? Am I doing anything wrong?

My `Listener factory` configuration

```
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setMessageConverter(messageConverter());
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    factory.setPubSubDomain(true);
    factory.setSubscriptionDurable(true);
    factory.setSessionTransacted(true);
    factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED);
    factory.setConcurrency("2-8");
    factory.setClientId("topicListener2");
    return factory;
```